# How to print a Task (including all columns)

Tags: 2010, printing

I need to print a task from a List in such a way that all columns are displayed properly. Currently when I print from IE, the output is incomplete i.e. it prints only the area in display and rest of the task is not printed. How to solve this issue?
All help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you define "displayed properly" a bit more and where are users expecting to print from, like the allitems view?

Comment: Have edited the Question.

Comment: Are you tyring to print a task from the modal view (popup that appears when clicking a task in the task list? Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was Silverlight. When a task was printed from a silverlight view there used to be lots of junk but if the task was open in HTML (Ctrl + Left Click), the print out was perfect.